# emscripten: How to delete memory of std::vector allocated in C++ code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, emscripten, asm.js

I want to know how to properly delete the memory of std::vector allocated in  c++ code and passed to js as function return.

My c++ code is

```
#include <vector>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

using namespace emscripten;

std::vector<int> intArrayToVector(uintptr_t input, int num){
std::vector<int> vec;
const int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(input);
for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    int val = *(ptr+i);
    vec.push_back(val);
}
return vec;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(test){
register_vector<int>("VectorInt");
function("intArrayToVector", &intArrayToVector, allow_raw_pointer<arg<0>>());  
}
```

My html code is

```
<html>
<body>
 <script src="test.js"></script>
 <script>
   var num = 6;
   var buf = Module._malloc(100);
   var arr = new Int8Array(num);
   for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
      arr[i] = i+2;
   }
Module.HEAP8.set(arr, buf);
var v = Module.intArrayToVector(buf, num);

for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
    console.log(v.get(i));
}
Module._free(buf);

v.resize(0, 0);
v.delete();  
v = {};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following code to delete the allocated memory but nothing is happening.

```
v.resize(0, 0);
v.delete();  
v = {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `v.delete()` works.

```
for (var j = 0;; j++) {
    var v = Module.intArrayToVector(buf, num);

    for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
        console.log(v.get(i));
    }
}
```

Above infinite loop aborts by `Cannot enlarge memory arrays.`

But with `v.delete()` at end of loop, this program doesn't stop.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
my problem is in below code.

After resizing the "std::vector < Edge > edges', it is not releasing the memory.

if i use "struct Edge *edges = new struct Edge[nEdges]; delete[]  edges; edges = NULL;" there is no memory leak

**
std::vector<unsigned int> GetFeatureEdges(float fCreaseAngle, uintptr_t input, int nTriangles, bool bBoundaryEdgesOnly) 
{

    std::vector < Edge > edges;
    const float* coords = reinterpret_cast<float*>(input);

    int nEdges = 3 * nTriangles;
    edges.resize(nEdges);
**

Do you have any idea?

Comment: thanks, please check this link for my code [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497630/emscripten-memory-leak-with-stdvector-stdmap-in-c-code)